# Should we participate in the Stack Exchange Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

*taken from the promo email*

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard that looks something like this:

[image]

Winter Bash 2013 will again be available to all sites that choose to participate. We’re redesigning the landing page and redesigning all the hats to keep things fresh and exciting.

Some Details

This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

> Should we participate in the 2013 Winter Bash ? I've created two
>   comments to vote on. Please express your preference by voting on the
>   comment you agree with.

Comment: **YES**, I think we should participate in the winter bash.

Comment: **NO**, I don't think we should participate in the winter bash

Comment: **SHRUG** I don't really care if we do or not.

Comment: **OTHER** maybe there are other/better ways to encourage participation here worth exploring

Comment: @vzn this is not my idea. It's something that the SE overlords do each year.

Comment: am aware of that, as the text states 1st line "taken from the promo email". had a hat last year for a few days. its the (harmless) default if there is no opposition. one of the community managers anna lear says its more up to each site to do their own promotion...

Comment: [stackexchange site/community promotion ideas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) by Cartaino, stackexchange director of community development

Comment: @vzn Y'all are welcome to come up with something else to do, but that's entirely unrelated to this event. Still gotta pick whether or not you want hats in the meantime.

Comment: hi anna! =) all due respect "event" might be an overstatement :p

Comment: see also [promoting tcs.se](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/promoting-tcs-stackexchange)

Comment: Given the 10 votes in favor, and the 4 against, I submitted a note saying that we opt in.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: Despite my earlier shrug, I miss my Chuck Yeager hat that I don't know why I won. And it's only been gone five minutes.

Answer (score 11):

At the time I write this, the leading option in the poll is [SHRUG](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/should-we-participate-in-the-stack-exchange-winter-bash#comment6819_2738).

If SHRUG wins, then instead of hats, CSTheory should get epaulettes.

[image: Suresh with badly cut epaulettes]

Comment: I'm on the "don't care side", but I think that SHRUG votes should be ignored (because they mean "I don't care about hats") and the decision should be based on the YES vs NO votes

Comment: Since participating is optional, one might argue that YES + SHRUG is a good measure.

Comment: its nice to see the community has some major passion/engagement for SHRUGging :p

Comment: Now that the hats have come out, every time I see one, I think of this post and laugh out loud. Thanks, Gilles.